# Get accessed to plucked object using javascript and lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of users in my javascript. For each user I am comparing if that user appears in another list.

```
var users = USERS.getUsers();

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var u = users[i];
    if (util.pluck(myList.adminUsers, 'email').includes(u.email)) {
        // How do I check the value of the plucked value for myList.adminUsers.locationId ? 
        u.status = "admin";
    } 
}
```

users is an array of user objects.

```
[{...}]
    0:
        id: "1"
        email: "johndoe@gmail.com"
        firstname: "John"
        lastname: "Doe"
        roleid: "1" 
        _proto__: Object
    1:
        id: "2"
        email: "janedoe@gmail.com"
        firstname: "Jane"
        lastname: "Doe"
        roleid: "1"
        _proto__: Object
```

`myList.adminUsers` is also an array of user objects but also with `locationId`.

```
[{...}]
    0:
        id: "1"
        email: "johndoe@gmail.com"
        firstname: "John"
        lastname: "Doe"
        roleid: "1"
        locationId: "123"
        _proto__: Object
```

I need to compare another field in this check. So I need to see if the plucked object from `myList.adminUsers` has a field locationId that equals `x`, but I'm not sure how to do this?

How can I get access to the plucked object so I can check the value of `locationId`?

Comment: I don't see `pluck` in the Lodash documentation. Are you using underscore.js?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`findWhere`](https://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) instead of `pluck`. You can give it an object containing all the properties you want to match.

```
if (util.findWhere(myList.adminUsers, {email: u.email, locationId: u.locationId})) {
    u.status = "admin";
}
```

Comment: `{email: u.email, locationId:u.locationId}`?  will that test a conjunction?

Comment: Yes. The documentation says it has to match *all* the key-value pairs provided.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the list of admins that are found in the list of users and are in the location ID you provide as a value (I set it as a variable).

```js
const users = [
  {
    id: "1",
    email: "johndoe@gmail.com",
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    roleid: "1" 
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    email: "janedoe@gmail.com",
    firstname: "Jane",
    lastname: "Doe",
    roleid: "1"
  }
];

const admins = [
  {
    id: "1",
    email: "johndoe@gmail.com",
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    roleid: "1",
    locationId: "123"
  }
];

const locationIdToFind = '123';

const adminsWithLocation = _.intersectionWith(admins, users, (admin, user) => _.isEqual(admin.email, user.email) && _.isEqual(admin.locationId, locationIdToFind));

console.log(adminsWithLocation);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```